# Run method only once when IIS starts ASMX service, then store results globally

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

Firstly I must apologise if my terminology is off. This is the first time I've explored `.asmx` so I've probably gotten some things wrong. I'm mentioning this because **I want you to correct me** as it is an invaluable learning experience and I need to get it right.

I'm writing an Ajax enabled `.asmx` web service to allow two browser based systems to talk to each other. In order for this to work I must initially authenticate with one of the systems to get the URL to use for all subsequent API calls to that same system. I only want to do this one time when the service is started and then remember this across all calls to all webmethods.

- How do I run a method only one time when the service is loaded
  by IIS?
- How do I store the result globally so that it can be
  accessed by every call to my webmethods?

I've seen two posts that touch on this ( [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144659/asmx-equivalent-of-page-init) | [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328666/c-sharp-how-to-initialize-webservice)  ) but neither made enough sense to help me.

I think I need to add a `Global.asax` file and store the details in there, but I'm not sure if this is right and I still don't know how to run the method only once. Can I just override `Application_Start` in here? This is what I would do on an ASPX page but I don't know how similar these two technologies are.
 I've seen recommendations to use the constructor to run the method but it's my understanding that this may be called more than once so would be incorrect for my scenario.

For clarity my project currently only has two files, handler.asmx and handler.cs.

**Handler.asmx**

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/handler.cs" Class="Handler" %>
```

**Handler.cs**

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://localhost/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)] 
[ScriptService]
public class Handler : WebService {

    public Handler () {
    // empty
    }

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string GetSomeInformation() {
    // does some stuff and then returns a string
    }
}
```

This is what the Global.asax looked like after I added it:

**Global.asax**

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>

<script runat="server">

    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
    }

    void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
    }

    // and all the other methods here like error, session start/end etc
```

Comment: Yes, you can create a global.asax and add the standard event handlers such as application_start, etc.

Comment: I've added a `Global.asax` file but I can't see that `Application_Start` ever fires. I'm running `IISRESET` each time which should fire this event. I've tried inserting a break point in there and also writing a local file, but neither seem to happen. I'm unsure what might be wrong.

Comment: Do you have something like this:   public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
 {
  public Global()
  {
   InitializeComponent();
  } 
  
  protected void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

  }

Comment: I could be wrong but I didn't think ASMX services derived from HttpApplication so I have nothing like that in my project. For clarity I have added a basic outline of what the service looks like above. There's really not much more code than that. Further reading seems to suggest that this is also the reason why global.asax might not work but I can't find concrete evidence either way so I'm a little confused!

Comment: Not asmx services, the global.asax does

Comment: Can you add your global.asax file? Asp.Netdhould call the application_start once during start-up

Comment: I've added the global.asax already, it's the last piece of code in the question.

Comment: This should work. Does your breakpoint not hit when you start with F5

Comment: If don't want to deal with this, define a static constructor for your service class an deal with things there..

Comment: It will be invoked only once, but should implement it with extra caution. Any failure is Fatal and will require a recycle

Comment: No, the breakpoint is never hit. I'd read about using the constructor but there were issues with this and I was trying to avoid it if possible. Global.asax definitely seems like the right solution, I'm just at a loss as to why it doesn't work. I have to leave now so I'll play with this overnight and see what I can do. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Why don't you instead implement an on-demand approach? Get the necessary information when it is needed, cache it, and return from cache for the rest of the calls.